# operator+ overload returning object causing memory leaks, C++

Tags: c++

The problem I think is with returning an object when i overload the + operator. I tried returning a reference to the object, but doing so does not fix the memory leak. I can comment out the two statements:

```
dObj = dObj + dObj2;
```

and

```
cObj = cObj + cObj2;
```

to free the program of memory leaks. Somehow, the problem is with returning an object after overloading the + operator.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vld.h>

    using namespace std;

    class Animal
    {
    public :
        Animal() {};
        virtual void eat()  = 0 {};
        virtual void walk() = 0 {};
    };

    class Dog : public Animal
    {
    public :
        Dog(const char * name, const char * gender, int age);
        Dog() : name(NULL), gender(NULL), age(0) {};

        virtual ~Dog();
        Dog operator+(const Dog &dObj);

    private :
        char * name;
        char * gender;
        int age;
    };

    class MyClass
    {
    public :
        MyClass() : action(NULL) {};
        void setInstance(Animal &newInstance);
        void doSomething();

    private :
        Animal * action;
    };


    Dog::Dog(const char * name, const char * gender, int age) :  // allocating here, for data passed in ctor
            name(new char[strlen(name)+1]), gender(new char[strlen(gender)+1]), age(age)
    {
        if (name)
        {
            size_t length = strlen(name) +1;
            strcpy_s(this->name, length, name);
        }
        else name = NULL;
        if (gender)
        {
            size_t length = strlen(gender) +1;
            strcpy_s(this->gender, length, gender);
        }
        else gender = NULL;
        if (age)
        {
            this->age = age;
        }
    }
    Dog::~Dog()
    {
        delete name;
        delete gender;
        age = 0;
    }

    Dog Dog::operator+(const Dog &dObj)
    {
        Dog d;
        d.age = age + dObj.age;
        return d;
    }

    void MyClass::setInstance(Animal &newInstance)
    {
        action = &newInstance;
    }
    void MyClass::doSomething()
    {
        action->walk();
        action->eat();  
    }
    int main()
    {
        MyClass mObj;

        Dog dObj("Scruffy", "Male", 4); // passing data into ctor
        Dog dObj2("Scooby", "Male", 6);

        mObj.setInstance(dObj); // set the instance specific to the object.
        mObj.doSomething();  // something happens based on which object is passed in

        dObj = dObj + dObj2; // invoke the operator+ 
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you putting yourself through this pain?  If you use `std::string`, you don't have to worry about managing the memory yourself.

Comment: I need to allocate the memory..

Comment: @lampshade: As in you're not allowed to use `string`? Or something else?

Comment: @lampshade: `std::string` allocates the memory for you.

Comment: Right, I need to allocate, using char*'s.

Comment: So...  this is homework?

Comment: @lampshade: *Why?*

Comment: Good question, ran into the same problem too. This seems to be a common pitfall.

Comment: Use deleaker or similar tool. i usually use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to declare copy constructor since you are returning object in overloaded operator +, the compiler automatically generates one for you if you dont explicitly define it, but compiler are stupid enough to not do deep copy on pointers

to summarize your mistake in the code posted:

1.) No Copy-Constructor/Assignment-Operator defined (**deallocation exception/ memory leak here**)
Since you are dealing with pointers, the compiler generated functions only perform shallow copy.
It is you job to make sure such behavior is intended, otherwise redefine it yourself into :

```
Dog::Dog(const Dog& ref) :
_name( strdup(ref._name) ), 
_gender( strdup(ref._gender) ), 
_age( ref._age )
{
}

Dog& Dog::operator=(const Dog &dObj)
{
    if (this != &dObj)
    {
        free (_name);
        free (_gender);
        _name = strdup( dObj._name );
        _gender = strdup( dObj._gender );
        _age = dObj._age;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

2.) Poor handling on pointer passed in (**Memory leak here**) 
You performed allocation before verifying null state on input parameters. 
It is smart move to additionally extra allocate 1 char of memory but you do not deallocate them after finding input parameters are null. A simple fix similar to copy-constructor above will be :

```
Dog::Dog(const char * name, const char * gender, int age) :
_name( strdup(name) ), 
_gender( strdup(gender) ), 
_age( age )
{
}
```

3.) Improper pairing of allocator/deallocator (**Potential memory leak here**)
Array allocation with new[] should match with array deallocation delete[], otherwise destructor for array element will not be handled correctly. 
However, to be consistent with sample code posted above using strdup (which internally make use of malloc), your destructor should be as below :

```
Dog::~Dog()
{
    free (_name);
    free (_gender);
    _age = 0;
}
```

Comment: I did that, and in the operator+ function I had d = *this, and transfered the data over, b/c it was called on that statement. It didnt help though.

Comment: you need to read up on Copy Constructor, which has the prototype of accepting reference of same type.

Comment: also, in case of the name/gender are null, you are allocating 1 char for each of them, then set the pointer to null afterward without releasing them, this causes memory leaks.

Comment: just realized you are using same name for member variables and function parameter, which is really bad practice. your code interpretation will depend on compiler (although most compiler will get it right), and not human-friendly readable. try look up for naming convention and stick to them.

Comment: A lack of Copy-Constructor/Assignment-Operator usually doesn't cause leaks -- what you usually get is two different instances of the Dog class sharing the same object. Then one gets deleted, and the destructor cleans up its internals, leaving the other pointing at freed memory.

Comment: It's a good idea to avoid variable names with leading underscores: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier .  It wouldn't cause a problem in this case, since the variables are all lower case, but if any of them started with an underscore and a capital letter, they'd be reserved by the implementation.

Comment: @Ken, lack of assignment operator does cause memory leaks, as the previous held memory are not freed before overwriting the reference (pointer).

Comment: @YeenFei. I agree that here it does, but in this case he just got lucky that his usage pattern made it work out that way rather than leading to segfaults.

Comment: Thanks Guys! I did not know that I needed to overload the assignment operator..And I also neglected to define a deep copy for both classes! I really appreciate all your help..

Answer (score 5):

If you are going to do your own memory management (which you *shouldn't*; use `std::string`!), you need to make sure that your class has the following user-defined functions:

- a destructor
- a copy constructor
- an assignment operator

(In addition, you'll usually have a user-defined constructor, too)

You have a user-defined destructor (thought you need to use the array `delete[]`, not the scalar `delete`), but you do not have a user-defined copy constructor or assignment operator, so any time you copy an object or assign an object, it ends up doing a memberwise copy.  Two objects then have the same pointers, and when they both get destroyed, the pointers get deleted twice--a big no-no.

Answer (score 4):

Use `std::string` and all your problems go away.
Afterall you tagged the question as C++ so you should use C++ standard libraries.  There's really absolutely no reason why you should not use `std::string`.

Of course you don't need to use `char*` allocations because this question isn't homework as it's not tagged as homework. Right?

Comment: while using de facto c++ library is good way to increase productivity, one should also understand the theory behind object-oriented design in c++.  I couldn't make myself imagining future developer who doesn't understand C++ Big 3 trying to debug memory issues or optimizing their program though conscious usage of shallow/deep copy mechanism.

Comment: @Yeen: Then if he wants to learn how string works, he should write a string class. Mixing it with other crap is not helpful at all. Write a single string class to know how it works, call it good, then get back to real programming.

Comment: @GMan: I was writing basically the same comment then I pressed cancel :)

Comment: @GMan, writing own class could be good idea too but aiming at broader scope, one should learn the Big 3, how to play with stack/heap object and pointer/reference.

Comment: @Yeen: Which one would do by writing a string class.

Comment: @YeenFei: His problem here is that he should use std::string.  I'm not against him learning the theory of using `char*`/`delete`/`new`, it's just that is not his problem in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Another tangential bug: after calling the + operator and the assignment operator, `dObj.name` and `dObj.gender` are now null, because the `Dog d` that you declare as the return value in `operator+` was created using the default constructor, and you didn't reassign `name` or `gender` before returning the new object.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be cause:

```
delete[] name;
delete[] gender;
```

Comment: while this answer is technically important (and should be fixed, because it can cause other kinds of brokenness on some C++ compilers), it's not the cause of the bug in this code.

Answer (score 0):

You're allocating the name & gender with `new char[]`, so you need to deallocate it with `delete [] name;`.  Whenever you allocate an array, you must delete the array.

As the comments noted, save yourself the trouble and use std::string! :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in

```
Dog::Dog(const char * name, const char * gender, int age) :  // allocating here, for data passed in ctor
            name(new char[strlen(name)+1]), gender(new char[strlen(gender)+1]), age(age)
```

and

```
Dog::~Dog()
{
    delete name;
    delete gender;
    age = 0;
}
```

Your `new[]`  needs to be matched with a `delete[]`, not a `delete.`

Answer (score 0):

Everyone has given the reason for the leak

There is one thing i would like to point out

```
Dog::~Dog()
{
    delete name;
    delete gender;
    age = 0;
}
```

There is no need to do `age=0`, this is useless since the object ceases to exist after the destructor.

Answer (score 0):

You need a copy constructor that deletes the memory on the old object before copying over the new object. The problem is that:

```
dObj = dObj + dObj2;
```

The result of the + is overwriting dObj's old char*'s with NULLs (from the returned object in your operator+) without deallocating those char*'s first.

Comment: the proper term for above is "assignment operator".   
Copy constructor, will never have "old object" since they are, in process of creation.   

the pointers of dObj should be left as it is during the exection scope of "operation +" because it is returning a "copy" of result object.    

when it came to "operation =" @ assignment, it is require to handle previous pointer stored in dObj before accepting values from newly created result object.

Answer (score 0):

Though it doesn't affect your problem (since you're not dynamically allocating any `Dog`s) if you're since you're declaring the virtual `~Dog` destructor in your in the `Dog` class, you probably also need to declare a virutual `~Animal` destructor in the `Animal` class, even if it does nothing.

That way, if you:

```
Animal* a=new Dog();
delete a;
```

then `Dog`'s destructor will be called.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the cause of your memory leak, but your `Animal` class needs to have a virtual destructor.  Otherwise, if you were to write:

```
Animal *dog = new Dog("Spot", "Male", 5);
delete dog;
```

then you would be leaking memory even after fixing any other problems, because without a virtual destructor in your `Animal` class, the `Dog` destructor will never get called to free the memory allocated in the `Dog` constructor.

This didn't happen in your case because you created your Dogs as automatic variables on the stack, which is good.